# How to combine different react native bundles in existing native app

Tags: javascript, react-native, javascriptcore, react-native-modules

I am working on an existing native app where three different partner companies are working so three different react-native modules.

Here the problem is when they are creating a javascript bundle, it includes javascript core also in each bundle that is increasing the size of a native app.

Does anyone know what is the correct way to handle this problem?

Comment: Could you show project structure? Example package.json. I guess custom react native library must not includes own JSC.